# Creating a counter using JavaScript dynamic object within switch()

Tags: javascript, object, dynamic, counter

I am trying to add a counter into the code below.

I am iterating over DOM elements in my page and converting a text string into an object. I am trying to create an object of the following prototype:

```
// my desired object layout:
eligList = {
    'perfect': {
        'id': 1,
        'qty': 3
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    eligList = {};
    // FROM: http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/jquery-each-examples/
    $(selector).each(function(index, value) {
        $this = $(this);  // cache
        apr   = parseFloat($.trim($this.find('.apr .js-apr').text()));
        eligName  = $.trim($this.find('.eligibility .js-hist').text());

        eligList[eligName] = (eligList[eligName] || {});

        switch(eligName) {
            case 'perfect':
                eligID = 1;
                // THE PROBLEM!
                console.log('eligList', eligList.perfect); // empty :s
                eligList[eligName]['qty'] = (eligList[eligName]['qty']++ || 1); // eligList.perfect.qty never gets set (at all)
                break;  
            case 'excellent':
                eligID = 2;
                break;  
            case 'good':
                eligID = 3;
                break;  
            case 'average':
                eligID = 4;
                break;  

            default:
                eligID = 5;
                break;  
        }

        eligList[eligName] = {'id': eligID};

        $this.data({'apr': apr, 'elig': eligID});

        console.group('article ' + index);
            console.log(apr);
            console.log(eligID);
        console.groupEnd();
    });

    console.log(eligList);
});
```

I suspect this is a scope issue. So, my question is how can I make my script count the `quantity` of `perfect`, `excellent`, `good` etc?

Comment: shouldn't your `console.log('eligList', eligList.perfect)` come after you assign, not before?

Comment: Oops, I had done some refactoring before I posted this. The overall problem is still valid :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working version:

```
<ul>
    <li id="test1">
        <span class="apr"><span class="js-apr">465464564</span></span>
        <span class="eligibility"><span class="js-hist">perfect</span></span>
    </li>
    <li id="test2">
        <span class="apr"><span class="js-apr">465464564</span></span>
        <span class="eligibility"><span class="js-hist">good</span></span>
    </li>
    <li id="test3">
        <span class="apr"><span class="js-apr">4222222</span></span>
        <span class="eligibility"><span class="js-hist">excellent</span></span>
    </li>
    <li id="test4">
        <span class="apr"><span class="js-apr">12121</span></span>
        <span class="eligibility"><span class="js-hist">excellent</span></span>
    </li>
</ul>

$(document).ready(function() {
    eligList = {};
    // FROM: http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/jquery-each-examples/
    $('ul li').each(function(index, value) {
        $this = $(this);  // cache
        apr   = parseFloat($.trim($this.find('.apr .js-apr').text()));
        eligName  = $.trim($this.find('.eligibility .js-hist').text());

        if(!eligList[eligName]){
            eligList[eligName] = {
                id : null,
                qty : 0
            }
        } else {
            eligList[eligName] = eligList[eligName];
        }

        switch(eligName) {
            case 'perfect':
                eligID = 1;                
                break;  
            case 'excellent':
                eligID = 2;
                break;  
            case 'good':
                eligID = 3;
                break;  
            case 'average':
                eligID = 4;
                break;
            default:
                eligID = 5;
                break;  
        }

        eligList[eligName].id = eligID;
        eligList[eligName].qty++;

        $this.data({'apr': apr, 'elig': eligID});

        console.group('article ' + index);
            console.log(apr);
            console.log(eligID);
        console.groupEnd();
    });

    console.log(eligList);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JQEKz/

Comment: So, it appears I was trying to be too clever :s
Your solution worked, thank you very much